# angularJS using constructor in ng-repeat but css style and position won't get applied?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I've been using ng-repeat to construct tables for a while now, and this is the first time I have this problem,

```
ng-repeat="users in [].constructor(10) track by $index"
```

basically all the elements generated by the ng-repeat get ignored by some css (borders of the container) and the DIVS below, which have position relative, ignore the newly generated elements, and position themselves just after the original element that gets repeated with ng-repeat.

why is that?

I used the ng-repeat in the same table, above for the rows, and I don't have this problem, any clue?

https://jsfiddle.net/buwgq14a/28/

here a fiddle with everything, you can see the last section, footer, is in the middle, because it positions itself just after the first element of the ng-repeat, while the rest gets ignored and doesnt even get the borders!

thank you so much

Comment: ok, solved by myself, stupid mistake, I was giving a set height of 35px to the container of the ng-repeat, instead of putting 'height: 35px' to the row container... after putting 'height:100%' it fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved by myself, stupid mistake, I was giving a set height of 35px to the container of the ng-repeat, instead of putting 'height: 35px' to the row container... after putting 'height:100%' it fixed everything –